# How to send decoded JSON object From PHP TO jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I got following JSON response from my api reply

```
{
    "status": "success",  
    "mobile": "+14567878888",
    "address": "usa"
}
```

I converted my JSON response to php Variable using

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

Now i want to use that php variable inside my requested page in jquery how to disply my variable inside Jquery ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // var number = <?php echo json['mobile']; ?>;
    // alert(number); 
    // These codes do not work for me and 
    // How to display mobile number inside div writing code here  and i want alert
});
```

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Make an AJAX request to get the JSON.

Comment: `echo json_encode($json['mobile']);`

Comment: Why people mark my question duplicate ,,,i am asking question with respect to jquery using Jquery method ...The above suggested Question is irrelevant to my topic.

Comment: remove from duplicate and provide me satisfactory answer .why people are hurry in marking duplicate . it gives pain to question asker.